# Print the lines that only with all consecutive repeated characters

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a text file and I want to print only the lines that have all their characters are consecutively reapeated at least two times or more.
FOR EXAMPLE THE INPUT:

```
11
AAA
555227777
BBhh@@222
baabbb
1112
212211
baa
22333445
322113
```

The output should be:

```
11
AAA 
555227777
BBhh@@222
```

The output contains only these four lines because  they have only consecutively duplicate characters in order.

I have tried this code

```
grep '\(^\| \)\([   ])\2\1\($\| \)' INFILE
```

But its not working exactly.

Comment: `grep -E '^((.)\2+)+$'` should get you your desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sed -En 'h;:a;s/^(.)\1+//;ta;/^$/{x;p}' file
```

with commentary

```
sed -E -n '
    h            # store a copy of the line
    :a           # set label "a"
    s/^(.)\1+//  # from the start of the line, remove sequences of 2 or more repeated chars
    ta           # *if the pattern matched* jump to "a"
    /^$/ {       # if empty string:
        x        #   retrieve the original line
        p        #   and print it
    }
' file
```

Comment: glenn jackman thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Could you please explain this command  -En 'h;:a;s/^(.)\1+//;ta;/^$/{x;p}' for me?

Comment: It's exactly the same as the commented version

Comment: Yes its it, could you please explain your command factors?

Answer (score 2):

One way , using Gnu sed, could be:

```
sed -Ee '/^((.)\2+)+$/!d'  input.txt
```

Comment: @@Rakesh Sharma thanks for your command , could you please modify it for me to print only the lines with all consecutively repeated charactets three times exactly no more no less like 111444 or bbbcccfff111

Comment: `perl -lne 'print if /^((.)\2\2(?!\2))+$/'`

Comment: Thanks Rakesh Sharma , i have solved it by modifying your previous command to sed -Ee '/^((.)\2{2})+$/!d'  input.txt.